# Android NFC transceive() using NFCF tech (Sony Felica)

Tags: android, nfc

I am attempting to connect my Android tablet to a device using NFC and retrieve data from the device.

**What I've Tried**

Sending commands as it explains in the [nfc_device_detection_1.01.pdf](http://www.sony.net/Products/felica/business/tech-support/data/nfc_device_detection_1.01.pdf) (Chapter 4)

The android java doc for [transceive()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/NfcF.html)  mentions the

*"Applications must not append the SoD (length) or EoD (CRC) to the payload, it will be automatically calculated"*

I have therefore tried with and without the CRC, with and without the packet data length but the documentation is not clear on if I should leave it blank or if i should just not include it.

Another approach I have taken is following the diagram in chapter 2.2 of [format_sequence_guidelines_1.1.pdf](http://www.sony.net/Products/felica/business/tech-support/data/format_sequence_guidelines_1.1.pdf) (Sync Code followed by Request) but same results.

**The problem**

I do not know what command (bytes) to send as an argument into the transceive() method.**

**Questions**

Does anyone:

- have an example of NFCF communication?
- have more information on the protocol/command that should be used?
- know if the NFC Tag contain the bytes I need for the command?

**Code**

transceive() throws an IO Exception "Tag was lost".

I believe this is because my command bytes are not correct (I have used a range of different commands).

Last Note (I have also tired putting the transceive() in a while loop and closed and connected the communication each time)

```
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {

        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

        NfcF nfcf = NfcF.get(tag);

        nfcf.connect();

        byte[] command = new byte[] { (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00};

        byte[] response =  nfcf.transceive(command);

     }
```

Please comment if any additional information is required for your answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example function of how to send a "raw" command, given the target device (tag) IDm, the FeliCa command byte and the payload:

```
byte[] rawCmd(NfcF nfcF, byte[] IDm, byte felicaCmd, byte[] payload) throws IOException {
    final int len = payload != null ? payload.length : 0;

    final byte[] cmd = new byte[10 + len];
    cmd[0] = (byte) (10 + len);
    cmd[1] = felicaCmd;
    System.arraycopy(IDm, 0, cmd, 2, IDm.length);

    if (payload != null) {
        System.arraycopy(payload, 0, cmd, 10, payload.length);
    }

    nfcF.transceive(cmd);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this example code. Am I able to get the IDm and payload from the Tag?

Comment: `payload` is the bytes that you want to send with the command, for example the block addresses and bytes that you want to write. IDm is usually the ID of the tag.If you have a tag that supports multiple "Systems", each has its own IDm (which you can obtain from the response to the Poll command for the specific System Code).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help someone in the future.

```
byte[] transceiveProtocol(NfcF nfcF, int systemCode, int requestCode, int timeSlot) {

byte d0 = 6;
byte d1 = 0;
byte d2 = (byte)(systemCode>> 8 & 0xFF);
byte d3 = (byte)(systemCode>> 0 & 0xFF);
byte d4 = (byte)(requestCode & 0xFF);
byte d5 = (byte)(timeSlot & 0xFF);

byte[] command = { d0, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5 };

return nfcF.transceive(command);
}
```

Comment: How can i get felica card no. Please post the command which is needed to get that details.

Comment: Sorry I don't have access to that project any more.